# How does apache beam access bigtable data?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-bigtable

If [BigtableIO.Read](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.4.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableIO.Read.html) is run in dataflow, is the data being accessed via a bigtable node or going directly to bigtable tablets?

[Bigtable architecture](https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/overview#architecture) has:

> client requests go through a front-end server before they are sent to a Cloud Bigtable ***node***

and goes on to say:

> A Cloud Bigtable table is sharded into blocks of contiguous rows, called ***tablet***s to help balance the workload of queries... Tablets are stored on Colossus, Google's file system, in SSTable format

(The concern is if there is a dataflow job running at the same as users are making individual request that definitely go through the nodes, whether there will be a small or large amount of contention from the dataflow job. I would guess that if the dataflow job went through the nodes there would be significantly more contention as opposed to hitting the tablets directly.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Beam BigTable connector uses the Cloud BigTable's public API hence requests will be going through the BigTable front end server nodes.

See [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/google-cloud-platform/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigtable/BigtableServiceImpl.java) for bit more detail regarding BigTable client API usage of the Beam connector.

Comment: so if datastore uses bigtable then does this mean that when using dataflow+datastore+beam that it stands up many bigtable nodes to deal with the increased request volume?

Comment: Beam BigTableIO connector does not change your BigTable cluster configuration. It just connects to a given cluster for reading/writing.